# Dehumidifier Settings

Tags: dehumidifier

I do not understand the settings on our dehumidifier. I want to increase the dehumidification of our basement. This is the rainiest summer I have ever seen. Our two-year-old laminate basement floor is getting spongy. Should I set the dial to 50 or to 90? Which setting will eliminate more humidity? I am confused as to whether the setting chosen relates to how much humidity is allowed to remain, or does the setting control how much is eliminated?  Does a setting of 50 mean I want 50% humidity in our basement? Does a 90% setting mean I will have 90% humidity? Or does a 90% setting mean I am trying to get rid of 90% of the humidity?  This is exactly what I want right now. We do have central air but we try NOT to use it, not only because of the expensive hydro in this rural area, but also because we both hate air conditioning. We prefer to leave our windows open. With all the rain, I suspect these open windows are part of the problem.

Comment: Be aware the running dehumidifiers also consumes electricity. If they are running a lot you may want to look at the name plate voltage and current ratings and compare with the AC unit.

Comment: If you don't understand relative humidity, you may be too uneducated to make effective use of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

The number setting is usually the humidity setting that you want to achieve. These settings are usually not an exact control point but are relatively close. I have a dehumidifier in my basement that I set at 45%. This keeps my whole house humidity between 38% and 42% as shown on a hygrometer I keep on a shelf. Also, I run my furnace/air conditioning fan 24/7 to keep the whole house temperature the same in all areas. One thing to remember is that it may take many days to stabilize the humidity in your home at a given set point once you close up the house and turn on the A/C. This is the same with the A/C since every thing in your house (all the contents) are at the same temperature and humidity and it takes time to lower both to your comfort level. As for the spongy floor that could be from water trapped beneath the laminate floor coming from cracks in the concrete or from a raised water table in your area. Basement floor coverings are a great addition but only if you are 100% sure that your basement floor will not allow moisture to pass through. I tapped plastic to my basement floor and waited a few weeks to see if moisture collected under the plastic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I got the settings figured out last night after I posted the question but your answer is very much appreciated. The most important "setting" I had forgotten about was to open the vent/discharge so the hot air could be blown back into the room. I opened that vent, set the dehumidifier at 50%, or 4, and almost immediately lowered the relative humidity to 52%, from 60%. I also figured out that it's probably going to take quite a few days to get the humidity in the basement even lower. I did run the AC all day today. Again, thank you for your kindness.